# Searching feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, search

How is it possible to search feature in QGIS?

I have lots of points with `ID`. Is it possible to search points using `ID`?

**Update:** I'm looking for a solution that centres the map to that point.

Comment: Find by attributes seems nice for what I want to do. I have tried Quick finder but no luck some error keep coming and I have submited that to the developer. Is Find by attribute available in QGIS 2.4 if yes what repository I can find it in?
Regards
Surag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Find by attributes" plugin has an "auto zoom" to the features that were found. It can reduce the number of necessary clicks.

Answer (score 12):

(For QGIS 3.x, Locator bar at the bottom of the window)

As @fuzzysolutions mentioned, use `f <search_term>` to search for **any attribute on the active layer**.

Use `af <search_term>` to **across all layers by Display Name** (configurable under Layer Properties -> Display)

`Search Layers` plugin is still needed to **search all layers by any attribute**.

Reference: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#locator-settings

Comment: On my 13300 rows x 32 columns dataset it spins, and spins... and nothing happens :(

Answer (score 10):

I am using `Search Layers` plugin for the searching all the features of all the layers of the of the project. It is working fine for me.

Yes, when you select a search result, it zooms to that particular feature.

Answer (score 4):

You have a search option in the attribute table , where you can search the features on the basis of their attribute fields.

Comment: how to search on map

Comment: when you search for a feature in the attribute table you will have a highlight selected feature button , which will display the selected feature on the map.

Comment: The limitation of this approach is a) too many steps: open attribute table or hit Cntrl-F, then enter the search command, then click ok, then go to the attribute table and select the particular row of interest from all those that match the search, then click zoom to selection. AND at the end of this, you only get to see the feature selected, other features become invisible, which often is not useful

Answer (score 4):

MMQGIS has some nice searching tools: http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

It's available as a plugin, and when installed, there's a white button available that does simple, fast searching on an attribute field. That works really well for searching for a value in a dataset you have.

It can also search using the Google Places API or Open Street Map, so you can search for anything at all.

I reckon MMQGIS is the one for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just to revive this old thread for others: Searching features (and many things more) has been greatly improved in QGIS 3.x by the [QGIS locator bar](https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#feature-locator-bar). There is less need for additional plugins now.

For features, type "f ATTRIBUTE" with any attribute - you get a list of suggestions with the field name and the respective attribute value. Select using the arrow keys, then press enter to zoom to it.

Comment: Any idea if we can select the feature located?

Answer (score 1):

You will have an option in the attribute table named zoom map to the selected rows(ctrl+j). That 'll do.
This is a late reply, But others might get some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

the query-builder should do the desired action (when I understand your question right).
right click on the point-layer in the left paneland select query and enter your query e.g. id >100

Comment: it doesn't move map to that point center map to that point

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too. In newer versions of QGIS haven't found any extension to do that. "find by attribute" was great. I have made a arcview 3.x extension to perform that job, you can download it here if you like: [download](http://elgeekforestal.blogspot.com/2015/03/herramienta-de-busqueda-de-atributos.html). I'll try to make it for QGIS but python is quite harder for me. Anyhow, I think my tool could help you if you have Arcview 3.x.