# How to search for text in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Does QGIS have any search capability, for example to find text within cadastral polygons?

---

Quantum gis posee algun buscador , por ejemplo para identificar textos en poligonos de catastro ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question is expected to include proof of basic research effort.

Comment: similar: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23059/how-to-search-feature-in-qgis?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Please check the QGIS user manual http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/03_vector_attribute_data.html

It shows the search in attribute table:

[image]